# VueJS bind input to Date value

Tags: vuejs2

I have `data` with `Date` fields startDate and stopDate:

```
    data: {
        error: '',
        config: {rate: 0.00, surcharge: 0.00, startDate: new Date(), stopDate: null, enabled: true},
        configurations: []
    },
```

Also I have input field:

```
<input id="startDate" type="date" v-model="config.startDate">
```

So while page creation I see warning in console:

> vue.js:7629 The specified value "Tue Sep 17 2019 15:52:44 GMT+0700
>   (\u041A\u0440\u0430\u0441\u043D\u043E\u044F\u0440\u0441\u043A,
>   \u0441\u0442\u0430\u043D\u0434\u0430\u0440\u0442\u043D\u043E\u0435
>   \u0432\u0440\u0435\u043C\u044F)" does not conform to the required
>   format, "yyyy-MM-dd".

Also, input field has no date value just after page has loaded. Seems like initial `Date` value has not bound to input field.

What is the natural way to bind date value to input field?
thanks for your answers and best regards.

Comment: try changing the input type to ''text" instead of date.

Comment: @VedprakashSingh But what if I want to have input field with build-in calendar support (type="date")?

Answer (score 0):

This is a working jsfiddle. I don't receive any error in console.log

> HTML

```
<div id="date">
 <p>
   New Date: <input id="startDate" type="date" v- 
   model="config.startDate">
   <span>{{config.startDate}}</span>
 </p>
</div>
```

> JS

```
var box = new Vue({
    el:'#date',
    data:{
    config: {rate: 0.00, surcharge: 0.00, startDate: new Date(), 
    stopDate: null, enabled: true}}
});
```

> https://jsfiddle.net/o6d1x9eb/

Comment: First, I use VueJS 2.6.10 as downloaded `.js` file in development mode. Maybe development mode makes more messages. Second, in the fiddle there is no value of current date in the input field. Seems like also doesn't work. Message is not a problem. The real problem is empty input field instead of current date value.

Answer (score 0):

According VueJS documentation, `v-model="config.startDate"` is equals to `v-bind:value="config.startDate" v-on:input="config.startDate = $event.target.value"`.
So, I have two ways:

1. Store in `config` variable of `data` value as `String` instead of `Date` and edit it by the input field. By the way, input field returns string value of date in yyyy-mm-dd format.
2. Use value as `Date`, filter (or function) to convert `Date` into `String` and function to convert `String` into `Date`.

So, the way I used is
for inpuut field:

```
<input id="startDate" type="date" 
v-bind:value="config.startDate | inputDateFilter" 
v-on:input="config.startDate = getDate($event.target.value)">
```

and for Vue instance:

```
    filters: {
        inputDateFilter: function (date) {
            if (!date) {
                return '';
            }
            date = new Date(date);
            return date.getFullYear() + '-' + ('0' + (date.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2) + '-' + ('0' + date.getDate()).slice(-2);
        },

        // . . .

    methods: {
        getDate(value) {
            if (!value) {
                return null;
            }
            return new Date(value);
        },

        // . . .
```

This is does what I want.